# cLion + QT - Linker Error when using Q_OBJECT

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion, qobject

I get a linker error if I put C_OBJECT into my header. 
Currently I copy my QT dll library to my project, otherwise, I get exit code error as I don't know how to add QT library in cMake yet... Not sure if that is causing the error. Maybe I need to add Q_OBJECT in CMakeList.txt somehow?

Here is the sample code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "testWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    testWidget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

testWidget.h

```
#ifndef QOBJECTCRASH_TESTWIDGET_H
#define QOBJECTCRASH_TESTWIDGET_H


#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

class testWidget : public QMainWindow
{Q_OBJECT   //this crashes the app. Remove it and all runs.

public:
    testWidget(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
};


#endif //QOBJECTCRASH_TESTWIDGET_H
```

testWidget.cpp

```
#include "testWidget.h"

testWidget::testWidget(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent) {
    setWindowTitle("Test Q_OBJECT");
    setGeometry(500,500,500,500);
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(QObjectCrash)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.9\\mingw53_32")


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp testWidget.cpp testWidget.h)
add_executable(QObjectCrash ${SOURCE_FILES})


find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
qt5_use_modules(QObjectCrash Core Widgets Gui)
target_link_libraries(QObjectCrash Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui)
```

Error print from cLion:

```
CMakeFiles\QObjectCrash.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN10testWidgetD1Ev':
D:/QObjectCrash/testWidget.h:11: undefined reference to `vtable for testWidget'
D:/QObjectCrash/testWidget.h:11: undefined reference to `vtable for testWidget'
CMakeFiles\QObjectCrash.dir/objects.a(testWidget.cpp.obj): In function `ZN10testWidgetC2EP7QWidget':
D:/QObjectCrash/testWidget.cpp:7: undefined reference to `vtable for testWidget'
D:/QObjectCrash/testWidget.cpp:7: undefined reference to `vtable for testWidget'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\QObjectCrash.dir\build.make:126: recipe for target 'QObjectCrash.exe' failed
        mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [QObjectCrash.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/QObjectCrash.dir/all' failed
        mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/QObjectCrash.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/QObjectCrash.dir/rule' failed
        mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/QObjectCrash.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [QObjectCrash] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'QObjectCrash' failed
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you have a moc file generated?

Comment: @vahancho I don't know what that is. If it did not generate automatically then I probably don't :- (

Comment: @vahancho I've added set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) but that seem to not help :- (

Comment: The only thing I can point to is this docs page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html .

Comment: Looks like I got it to work ! Adding the CMAKE_AUTOMOC_ON and target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets) - not sure but it seem to fix it! My test now compile. Signals still dont work but thats issue for another topic I guess . Thanks for your time and help ! The MOC info did the trick !